# Method to test if arrays are the reverse of each other not passing test

Tags: arrays, if-statement, methods

I'm supposed to make a method to test if two arrays have the same values in reverse order.

```
public static boolean areReversed (int [] t , int [] q)
{
  boolean identical = false;
  if(t.length != q.length){ identical = false;}
  else{
  for(int x = (t.length -1) , y = 0; -1 < x; x-- , y++)
  {
     if(t[y] == q[x])
     {
      identical = true;

     }

  }
}
  return identical;
```

}

I test it by running it through these if statements with the following pre-determined arrays

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    int[] b = {0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int[] d = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] e = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] f = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] g = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
    int[] h = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    int[] i = {1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9};

    //test for areReversed, uncomment the next two lines to test your method
    if(areReversed(a, b) && !areReversed(a, g) && !areReversed(a, c)) System.out.println("Basic areReversed method test PASSED");
    else System.out.println("Basic areReversed method test FAILED");
```

My method doesn't pass the test, am I making an oversight somewhere in my code?

Comment: I put in the wrong method before, this is the one I want to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
public static boolean areReversed (int [] t , int [] q)
{
  if(t.length != q.length) return false;
  for(int x = (t.length -1) , y = 0; -1 < x; x-- , y++)
  {
     if(t[y] != q[x]) return false;
  }
  return true; 
}
```

Note that I'm returning `false` from the method as and when it is known that the reversed arrays are unequal. Hence, at the end, if `false` isn't returned yet, the arrays have to be reversed equal, and thus, `true` is returned.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I understand the mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are indexing to two arrays in the same order. You are essentially checking that they are equal, not that they are the reverse of each other.

Also, remember that a function can return at any point Think about this and think about how you could make your function more efficient in a case where the arrays look like this:

[1,2,3] and [4,2,4].

How many comparisons do you actually need to make before you can tell us the arrays are not the same.